# Does $\exp(2ir\pi)$ equal $1$? What's wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Since $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$,
thus  $e^{2\pi i}=\cos2\pi+i\sin2\pi=1$

Now I take arbitrary real number $r$
then $e^{i2\pi r}=(e^{i2\pi})^r=1^r=1?$

But this cannot be true since $\cos2\pi r+i\sin2\pi r$  isn't necessarily $1$ for arbitrary $r$. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: What is wrong here, is that you did not define $a^b$ for a complex number $a$ and a noninteger $b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple:

$$(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$$

is an equality which only holds for real numbers with $a>0$ and does not necesarily hold on complex numbers.

Comment: It does not necessarily hold for real numbers either. If $a\gt 0$, and if $b$ and $c$ are real, then with the usual definitions it would hold.

Comment: More to the point: The problem with the relation $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ in the real case is the ambiguity in the sign, which can be resolved by taking $a > 0$. In the complex case, there are more than two choices for the sign and no obvious way of choosing one over another.

Comment: @anomaly: If $a<0$, there are more problems than sign.  What is $(-2)^\pi$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: That is, of course, a very good point. :) Anyway, the idea is that $\arg (a^b)$ should be $b \arg a$, but $\arg$ is only defined $\!\pmod{2\pi}$; if $b$ is not an integer, then it's unclear which particular value to take. (Ignore branch cuts, etc. for now). If $\arg a = 0$--- that is, if $a > 0$ (and real)--- then there's at least a canonical choice.